# How do I ignore artificial landscape (e.g., pavement, cars, buildings) in order to classify features of the natural landscape (e.g., veg cover, soil)?

Tags: classification, road, image-classification

I want to classify the landscape into different classes, in order to identify areas with low veg cover and bare soil. Unfortunately, any of the classification tools I use will recognize pavement, cars, and buildings as low veg cover and bare soil.

NDVI works okay, but roads and water have the same color. It would be great to class all the artificial features into one bin and class everything else separately. Is there a way to do this?

I currently use ArcGis Pro for GIS and R for data analysis, and do not have experience using Python for GIS.

Comment: What particular GIS software do you wish to ask about in this question?  If it’s a Python library then please include a code attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you review [Zhang, et.al, 2020](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/12/11/1831/htm) for a technique which identifies and removes buildings and hardscapes by geometry classification before performing landscape analysis.